tengo un problema con mini compilador de c en c
tengo una problema con un compilador en c para c es un mini compilador que sea capaz de hacer
el análisis léxico, semántico y sintáctico
La generación de código y la optimización del mismo
En este proyecto se involucra el diseño e implementación de diferentes fases de compilación como el analizador léxico, sintáctico y semántico
Así como la generación de código y necesito una ayuda por favor el codigo que le mostre al profesor me dijo que no era asi como lo tenia que en ves de ser una calculadora que se pueda poner un fragmento del codigo en c osea que se puedan crear operaciones aritmeticas y la creacion de arreglos en el codigo parecida en un compilador por ejemplo algo asi
int arreglo[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

y me dijo que no se fuerze los analisis por favor muchachos si me ayudan se los agradeceria mucho
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    char type[20];
    char value[20];
} Token;


//analisis lexico
Token* lexer(const char* input_string, int* num_tokens) {
    Token* tokens = malloc(sizeof(Token) * (strlen(input_string) + 1));
    if (tokens == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Fallo en la asignación de memoria.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (input_string[i] != '\0') {
        if (isspace(input_string[i])) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        if (isdigit(input_string[i])) {
            int j = 0;
            while (isdigit(input_string[i])) {
                tokens[index].value[j] = input_string[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            tokens[index].value[j] = '\0';
            strcpy(tokens[index].type, "NUMERO");
            index++;
            continue;
        }

        switch (input_string[i]) {
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
                tokens[index].value[0] = input_string[i];
                tokens[index].value[1] = '\0';
                strcpy(tokens[index].type, "OPERADOR");
                index++;
                break;
            default:
                if (isalpha(input_string[i])) {
                    tokens[index].value[0] = input_string[i];
                    tokens[index].value[1] = '\0';
                    strcpy(tokens[index].type, "CARACTER INVALIDO");
                    index++;
                } else {
                    printf("Error: Carácter inválido encontrado: %c\n", input_string[i]);
                    exit(1);
                }
                break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    *num_tokens = index;
    return tokens;
}

//analisis sintactico
int parseExpression(Token* tokens, int num_tokens, int current_token);

int parseFactor(Token* tokens, int num_tokens, int current_token) {
    if (current_token >= num_tokens) {
        printf("Error: Factor incompleto. Se esperaba un número o un paréntesis izquierdo.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (strcmp(tokens[current_token].type, "NUMERO") == 0) {
        return current_token + 1;} else {
        printf("Error: Se ha introducido un caracter inválido..\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}


int parseTerm(Token* tokens, int num_tokens, int current_token) {
    current_token = parseFactor(tokens, num_tokens, current_token);

    while (current_token < num_tokens && (strcmp(tokens[current_token].value, "*") == 0 || strcmp(tokens[current_token].value, "/") == 0)) {
        current_token = parseFactor(tokens, num_tokens, current_token + 1);
    }

    return current_token;
}

int parseExpression(Token* tokens, int num_tokens, int current_token) {
    current_token = parseTerm(tokens, num_tokens, current_token);

    while (current_token < num_tokens && (strcmp(tokens[current_token].value, "+") == 0 || strcmp(tokens[current_token].value, "-") == 0)) {
        current_token = parseTerm(tokens, num_tokens, current_token + 1);
    }

    if (current_token < num_tokens) {
        printf("Error: Expresión inválida. Se encontró un token inesperado: (%s, %s)\n", tokens[current_token].type, tokens[current_token].value);
        exit(1);
    }

    return current_token;
}

void parse(Token* tokens, int num_tokens) {
    parseExpression(tokens, num_tokens, 0);
}

void printTokens(Token* tokens, int num_tokens) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tokens; i++) {
        printf("(%s, %s)\n", tokens[i].type, tokens[i].value);
    }
}


//analisis semantico
bool semanticAnalysis(Token* tokens, int num_tokens) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tokens; i++) {
        if (strcmp(tokens[i].value, "/") == 0) {
            // Verificar si existe una división entre cero
            if (i + 1 < num_tokens && strcmp(tokens[i + 1].value, "0") == 0) {
                printf("Error semántico: División entre cero no está permitida.\n");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}


//generación y optimización de codigo
void generateCode(Token* tokens, int num_tokens) {
    printf("Generando código...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < num_tokens; i++) {
        if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "NUMERO") == 0) {
            printf("PUSH %s\n", tokens[i].value);
        } else if (strcmp(tokens[i].type, "OPERADOR") == 0) {
            if (strcmp(tokens[i].value, "+") == 0) {
                // Verificar si la siguiente operación también es una suma
                if (i + 1 < num_tokens && strcmp(tokens[i + 1].value, "+") == 0) {
                    printf("ADD\n");  // Solo generamos una instrucción de suma
                    i++;  // Saltamos el siguiente operador
                } else {
                    printf("ADD\n");
                }
            } else if (strcmp(tokens[i].value, "-") == 0) {
                // Verificar si la siguiente operación también es una resta
                if (i + 1 < num_tokens && strcmp(tokens[i + 1].value, "-") == 0) {
                    printf("SUB\n");  // Solo generamos una instrucción de resta
                    i++;  // Saltamos el siguiente operador
                } else {
                    printf("SUB\n");
                }
            } else if (strcmp(tokens[i].value, "*") == 0) {
                printf("MUL\n");
            } else if (strcmp(tokens[i].value, "/") == 0) {
                printf("DIV\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char input_string[100];

    printf("Kevin Romero");
    printf("C.I 30.557.522\n");
    printf("Este programa realiza el análisis léxico, sintáctico y semántico de una expresión matemática simple.\n");
    printf("Las operaciones permitidas son: suma (+), resta (-), multiplicación (*) y división (/).\n");

    printf("Ingresa una operación matemática simple: ");
    fgets(input_string, sizeof(input_string), stdin);
    input_string[strcspn(input_string, "\n")] = 0;

    int num_tokens;
    Token* tokens = lexer(input_string, &num_tokens);

    printf("Tokens encontrados:\n");
    printTokens(tokens, num_tokens);

    printf("Analizando sintácticamente...\n");
    parse(tokens, num_tokens);

    printf("Análisis sintáctico exitoso. La expresión es válida.\n");

    printf("Analizando semánticamente...\n");
    if (!semanticAnalysis(tokens, num_tokens)) {
        printf("Análisis semántico fallido. La expresión contiene errores semánticos.\n");
        free(tokens);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Análisis semántico exitoso. La expresión es semánticamente válida.\n");

    generateCode(tokens, num_tokens);

    free(tokens);

    return 0;
}


ya probe de todo y nada investigue en youtube en github y nada que me funcione lo unico que espero es que sea parecido a un compilador con operaciones aritmeticas array y cadena de caracteres algo sencillo y que sea algo parecido a un idle

Vas a tener que cambiar algunas cosas entonces porque eso solo hace operaciones aritméticas. Si tienes que construir un compilador, puedes mirar proyectos de otros a ver cómo los hicieron. Por ejemplo https://github.com/rui314/8cc

Si eso ví pero aún no encuentro una solución ya que c es un lenguaje que yo en lo personal no domino ni nada y la verdad se me hace algo difícil por ahora estoy intentando investigar como lo puedo hacer pero si me ayudas te lo agradecería muchísimo brou

Lo siento. Nunca hice un compilador. Es una tarea bastante grande como para ayudarte. Te puedo sugerir que averigües qué instrucciones debe soportar. No creo que tu profesor te pida un compilador completo de C, solo algunas características

me pidio uno basico que haga operaciones aritmeticas o la verificacion de una matriz
